# Finding most frequent value and doing a join

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

so I'm really really struggling right now, I've pretty much looked everywhere and I cannot find the answer so I'm looking for some guidance.

I need to gather the task_name which has appeared most frequently within the task_tbl, I then need to find out  all the jobs within the job_tbl which have used that task (note, each value within the task_tbl has a foreign key reference to the job_tbl)

This code is what I currently have, and this will successfully return the most seen task_name, but I'm still unsure of how to figure out all the jobs which have used this task.

```
  select task_name
  from
  (select task_name, count(1) 
  from task_tbl
  group by task_name
  order by count(1) desc) a
     where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: If you are on Oracle 12.1 or later you can use the `fetch first` syntax to simplify top-n queries like this.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
select j.job_name
from job_tbl j
join task_tbl t
  on t.job_fk = j.job_id
where t.task_name in ( <your query> );
```

Assuming job_id is primary key on job_tbl, job_fk is foreign key column on task_tbl, and job_name is the column you want from job_tbl.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   job_tbl j
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   (SELECT task_name
                       FROM   (SELECT task_name,
                                      Count(1),
                                      ROWNUM rn
                               FROM   task_tbl
                               GROUP  BY task_name
                               ORDER  BY Count(1) DESC) a
                       WHERE  rn = 1) b
               WHERE  b.task_name = j.task_name)  ;
```

As suggested in one of the comments, If you are using Oracle 12c, you have another option. The inline view `a`  in the above query could be replaced by

```
SELECT task_name,
       COUNT(1)
FROM   task_tbl
GROUP  BY task_name
ORDER  BY COUNT(1) desc
FETCH first 1 ROWS only
```

excluding `rn = 1`